# How to put interface created with JavaFX on C code?

Tags: c, javafx

I am creating server/client application. The server and client parts should be written in C language. However, for user interface I would like to use javafx. So, the question is it possible to combine *javafx* with *C*? If it is, then how do i do this in a proper way?

Comment: see [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: You can [call C functions from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963266/call-c-function-from-java), but that's as close as you're going to get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, JavaFX is a Java API. You cannot use it from C. While you can use C and Java in the same process e.g. by creating JNI bindings, that requires substantial development effort and implies some performance overhead, as JNI has to copy all data between its C representation and its Java representation. It would likely be much easier and result in a much more stable program, if you either

- write your client completely in Java, or
- write your GUI in C or C++ as well.

Answer (score 2):

So you are writing a program in C (your client code probably) and you want to add some user interface to it.

Notice that the C11 standard (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) provides very limited features for user interaction (basically, program arguments and `<stdio.h>`). You probably want to use some external library, which usually would be [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) dependent.

You could at first consider making a command line program. Then your C program simply parses the program arguments given to it (i.e. arguments to `main`) and act accordingly. Even that is often OS specific, but [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307472/40065) provides some guidance. FYI, the GNU [Glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc) library documentation has a chapter on [parsing program arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html).

You might also define some syntax and semantics for your standard input, and use common [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques on it. You could use [recursive descent parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) techniques. But that might not be very user friendly (because your user could not *easily* edit his/her input).

On many systems, the user could interact with your program thru a [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) (which is much more complex than what `<stdio.h>` provides). On Unix or POSIX systems, read about [the tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/), and use libraries like [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) or preferably [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) (or at least [readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)).

You could consider providing some [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface). In practice, you then need to use some [toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit), like [GTK](https://gtk.org/) (or [Qt](https://qt.io/) in C++) or [libSDL](https://www.libsdl.org/).

You might expect your user to use his/her web browser. Then you want to add some Web interface. For that, you should make your C program a specialized web server, using some HTTP server library like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [libhttp](https://www.libhttp.org/). Of course, you then need to be familiar with web technologies, including HTTP, HTML5, CSS, AJAX.

Since you mention [JAVAFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) in your question, you might split your software in several processes doing [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (then you would have a user interface program written in Java communicating with your C programs; how that is achieved is operating system specific).